# how to change xy axis with matplot in python

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

corona_data = pd.read_csv("서울시 코로나19 확진자 현황 csv.csv", encoding="cp949")
confirmed_dates = corona_data["확진일"]

confirmed_date = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in confirmed_dates]
corona_data["확진일"]= confirmed_date

plt.rc('font', family='Malgun Gothic')
corona_data["확진일"].plot(title="확진일 별 확진자 추이")

plt.show()
```

This plot show x-axis is just number and y-axis is date but I wanna change x-axis is date and y-axis is number how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a dataframe, I recommend using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) to visualize it. It has a great API that allows you to plot elements of your dataframe by referening column names. Here is a toy example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv(...)
# Plot scatter plot
sns.scatter(x='col_1', y='col_2', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Check out the Seaborn documentation for more

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your dataframe only contains one dataset which are the dated. You could add a column that contains the row numbers and then select what you want to have on x and y axis by passing the column name to the plot function:

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

corona_data = pd.read_csv("서울시 코로나19 확진자 현황 csv.csv", encoding="cp949")
confirmed_dates = corona_data["확진일"]

confirmed_date = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in confirmed_dates]
corona_data["확진일"]= confirmed_date

# now add the numbers to the dataset
corona_data["numbers"]=[i for i in len(confirmed_dates)]

plt.rc('font', family='Malgun Gothic')
# and tell the plot function that you want "확진일" as x ans "numbers" as y axis
corona_data.plot("확진일","numbers",title="확진일 별 확진자 추이")

plt.show()```
````